# Redirect URI hasn't updated

Tags: facebook, meteor, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a Meteor app and am using the following function to login with facebook

```
fbLogin = function() {
    Meteor.loginWithFacebook({
        requestPermissions: ['public_profile', 'email', 'user_location']
    }, function(err) {
        if (err)
        // redirect to register if popup comes and user isn't on register
            Session.set('errorMessage', err.reason || 'Unknown Eror');
        console.log(Session.get('errorMessage'));
    });
}
```

The credentials are set and working properly ( app id and secret)

Recently, I updated my Facebook app settings with a new **Domain** and **Site url** and yet it does not let me login. It throw the:

> Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.

error with the redirect_uri parameter in the url set to the **old** site url

Is there possibly a delay on Facebook's end or some other issue at hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen when the redirect_uri submitted with the https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth request is not present in the list of Valid OAuth redirect URIs under:

Settings >> Advanced >> Security
 add a redirect_uri like  https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html as an example

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't seem to be fixing it.
Now I'm getting: 

`URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not 
whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings. Make sure Client and Web OAuth Login are on and add all your app domains as Valid OAuth 
Redirect URIs.`

Comment: what redirect uri did you add?

Comment: I added the home page of my site. I have a domain that points to another domain. In this case the url I want to use is pointing to an amazon url. Maybe the problem relates to this.

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem unless it is not a 'domain'.